# Не удается запустить Android эмулятор на Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, android

Программа не загружается дальше логотипа. Держал открытой пол дня, не включается. Даже не знаю как быть. Пробовал сторонний, он работает, но не подходит так так как не удалось интегрировать с софтом для разработки.

Comment: пробовали запустить эмулятор от имени администратора? есть подозрение, что он не может куда-то записать (нет прав на запись, а может и чтение), вот и висит.

Comment: А под Win 8.0 работало? У меня под 8-кой нормально работает - никаких проблем.

Comment: Эмулятор какой версии Android?    
У меня ни когда не запускались выше, чем 4.0.3 ни на 7, ни на 8, ни на 8.1

Comment: пробовал все версии, права админа, под 8.0 не смотрел.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что не хватает оперативки. версии 4 и выше требуют от 1.5 гига ОЗУ (по умолчанию).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). Вы будете удивлены скоростью :)

Подойдет для тестирования обычных приложений.

Comment: мне не удалось его с MoSync интегрировать

Comment: жаль, но про это IDE я не могу ничего сказать.

Comment: не работают проги, установленные из гугол маркета

Comment: "не работают проги, установленные из гугол маркета" не эмуляторе не все проги могут работать, так как эмулятор не поддерживает Google API